# The peculiar use of "parce que"

Tags: expressions

> Femme : Restez ici, je vais chercher le dessert.
>
> Homme : **Parce qu**'il y a un dessert, en plus ? Quel festin !

Obvioiusly, "parce que" here does not mean "because". I wonder, is this a colloquial expression or something?

---

**UPDATE:**

> Homme : Mais tu n’aimes pas les fantômes non plus, tu nous l’as dit !
>
> Femme : **Parce que** tu connais quelqu'un qui les aime, toi ?

I wonder if the « parce que » in this new example, too, serves to denote a sense of surprise?

> = Femme: "What?! You say you know someone who actually likes them?!" {with a hint of disbelief}
>
> = Femme: {it basically boils down to saying} "Who does?!"

Comment: I had no idea this was possibly colloquial, I use it in English too ! And to me, it does mean "because". I'd translate this as "Do you mean there's dessert ? What a feast !"

Comment: I would use it in English too, I must admit. *Oh, because* you *know someone who like them, huh?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formal use of "parce que" is to illustrate a causality or a reason.

- On me refuse l'accès parce que j'ai oublié mes identifiants.

In this context, it's an informal phrasing to emphasize an unexpected outcome to an already surprising sequence of events.

- Non seulement le dîner était parfait, mais il y avait un dessert en plus.

In this context it indicates pleasantness, but it could be used to indicate the opposite.

- Parce qu'en plus je n'ai pas le droit de sortir ?

I wouldn't be able to confidently categorize it but it looks like an idiomatic phrasing.

Comment: So essentially, does it denote a sense of surprise, whether it be a pleasant or unpleasant one? Merci.

Comment: Je vous en prie [ : And yes, absolutely. A dramatic emphasis on a sense of surprise.

Comment: @LUNA Indeed, you only say this if you didn't expect it. Here, you are saying the diner didn't need a desert to be perfect, but you just learnt there is actually one, what a good surprise ! :)

Comment: randomhopeful @Random I just added another example. Do you think I'm on the right track here? Merci. :)

Comment: @LUNA The example is pretty usable [ : In this instance, it's a bit of sarcasm disguised as surprise. Still, it is in the same spectrum.

Comment: I was just wondering, but when you use "parce que" this way, does it always have to take the form of a question? Merci.

Comment: @LUNA You're right ! It fits perfectly your 2nd example, and has to be a question

Comment: To me it's not necessarily a question or a surprise. If you say: *Parce qu'il y a un dessert, en plus ?!*, it's the perfect case of suprise and question. But if you say: *Parce qu'évidemment, il y a un dessert...*, in a sarcastic way, in a situation like everything you've already eaten was awful and here comes the desert, as expected (so the opposite of the surprise).

Comment: @SimonDéchamps You're absolutely right [ : Sarcasm is kind of a wildcard that can take the spirit of anything, especially faking being surprised. As for the question, it is obviously rhetorical in this context.